# Magento Api Calls return a void object

Tags: magento2, api, headless

I'm developing headless e-commerce using `Vuejs` and `Magento`.

But I'm facing an issue during the API calls to retrieve products in categories.
It returns a void list.

May someone help me?

Comment: Can you provide some code about what you tried, what API are you calling, and what are the parameters ? As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly where the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the method type mentioned correctly like "*POST*" or "*PUT*" in webapi.xml file.

```
<route url="/V1/params/:someString/items" method="PUT">
```

Comment: thanks, where can i find the webapi.xml file?

Comment: In app/code/etc folder @NecktieWebAgency